# Scala Play 2.7 re-executes action's body after 75s

Tags: playframework

Given the following action:

```
Action.async {
    implicit request: Request[AnyContent] => 
      logger.warn(s"CALL: $request")
      Future {
        blocking {
          Thread.sleep(120000)
          logger.warn("FINISHED")
          Ok("{}")
        }
      }
  }
```

I expect to see `CALL` at t=0s and `FINISHED` at t=120s. But what happens is the following:

```
t=0s: CALL
t=75s: CALL
t=120s: FINISHED
t=195s: FINISHED
```

Then the page renders "Connection was reset".

What is going on!?

Comment: I believe you're sending the second request while the first request is blocked as play accepts each request on a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that by default Play uses Akka.Http with a [host connection pool](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/host-level.html). This means that it re-sends a request automatically when the first request times out (`play.server.http.idleTimeout` defaults to 75s).
It is [specified](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/host-level.html#retrying-a-request) that only idempotent requests are retried and that's where I got it wrong: my request used GET but the action triggered on the server side was not idempotent. I should therefore have used POST instead.
[Source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/9657#issuecomment-534714875)

Comment: I don't think this is what is happening. Play uses Akka HTTP for the **server** backend only, and the links here are for Akka HTTP **client**-side. So, it is possible that your HTTP client is retrying the request after a timeout (default to 75 seconds). That is why I asked about which HTTP client you are using since I'm pretty sure that is what is happening.

Comment: That's a good point... I'm using jQuery.ajax(), but I added a printout in the method doing the ajax call and I can see that it is executed only once. So unless jQuery.ajax() (or Chrome but that is rather unlikely) does a re-try, I think it is Play that detects that he could not provide a response before a timeout and somehow re-submits the request to itself. But this is pure speculation!

Comment: Play does not have anything like that. I suggest you see the requests made by the browser using the inspector's network tab. But anyway, this is why I've recommended `curl` as the client because you have more control of how the request is made.